# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)

Tags: google-app-engine

Every now and then I come across this error. I usually end up cleaning all the database. what could be the cause?

This is on Win XP SP3, GAE 1.6.5, Objectify 3.0, GWT 2.4.

```
QueryResultIterator<Key<x>> it = query.fetchKeys().iterator(); 
ArrayList<Key<x>> keys = new ArrayList<Key<x>> (num);          
while (it != null && it.hasNext()) {                      <== error      
    keys.add(it.next());
}
```

Here is the error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:33)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.peekQueryResultAndIfFirstRecordIndexList(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:175)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:111)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:98)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.hasNext(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:66)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingIterator.hasNext(TranslatingIterator.java:29)
```

Comment: Why would you -1 this post without replying?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in GAEJ. I got this all the time, just wait for a day and it will work. Do not send any hit to the server. I know it is kind of bad. Even worse, I am a paying customer.

I hit the "Report production issue" every time it occurs and pray that someone will look into it.

Comment: Do you use objectify, are you using GAE java? When I login into the admin console, all data is displayed fine from there.